# Cannot assign value of type '[SKNode]' to type 'SKSpriteNode!'

Tags: swift3, sprite-kit, xcode8, ios10

I'm writing a Galaga-style game in Swift 3 with SpriteKit and I keep getting an error that says

> Cannot assign value of type '[SKNode]' to type 'SKSpriteNode!'

Can anyone explain what this means so that I can fix it myself in the future and also give me a possible solution?

Here's the function where I get the error:

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    for touch in touches {
        let location = (touch as UITouch).location(in: self)
        if fireButton = self.nodes(at: location) {
            shoot()
        } else {
            let touchLocation = touch.location(in: self)
            spaceship.position.x = touchLocation.x
        }
    }
}
```

I get the error on the line with `if fireButton = self.nodes(at: location)`

Comment: You need to typecast the SKSpriteNode class on that SKNode, I only know how to do it with Obj-C, I don't know swift (yet) sorry

Comment: Can you explain what it means to typecast something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `self.nodes(at: location)` returns an array of all SKNodes that intersect `location`. The error occurs because you are trying to assign the whole array of SKNodes (i.e. `[SKNode]`) to a variable that references only a single node.

Also note that since `self.nodes(at: location)` returns **all** the nodes that intersect the specific location, you will need to iterate through the array of nodes to find the node you are looking for.

To iterate through the array, I would suggest to replace the lines

```
if fireButton = self.nodes(at: location) {
        shoot()
}
```

with

```
let nodes = self.nodes(at: location)
for node in nodes {
    if node.name == "fireButton" {
        shoot()
    }
}
```

And at the place where you declare `fireButton` assign it a name as in

```
fireButton.name = "fireButton" 
// just an exmaple, rather store these names as constants somewhere in your code
```

That's the easiest way, but you need to remember all the names you gave to your sprites. An alterantive is to create a `FireButton` class as a subclass of SKSpriteNode, declare `fireButton` as an instance of `FireButton` and instead of checking for names, you can do

```
if node is FireButton { 
    shoot()
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Ok, what would be the best way to iterate the array?

Comment: Ok, it fixed that error, but now I get an error on the initialization of the fireButton sprite that says Thread 1 EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_1386_INVOP, subcode=0x0). I will try to figure this out myself because I think that I have already asked a question about this error. If you want to help feel free but I probably won't respond for a while. Thanks for the help!

Comment: You're welcome! The second error means you were accessing an object that does not exist (either it hasn't been initialized yet, or it has already been deallocated). I think the problem may be when you unwrap the optionals using ! . Try checking if the object is not nil before you forcefully unwrap it.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for all the help!