# Thread 1: signal SIGABRT error in SpriteKit game

Tags: ios, swift3, sprite-kit, xcode8

This question is related to a question that I had earlier about my Galaga game that I am making in SpriteKit.
 ([Cannot assign value of type '[SKNode]' to type 'SKSpriteNode!'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44479700/cannot-assign-value-of-type-sknode-to-type-skspritenode/44490294#44490294)) I am just continuing the conversation that I had going there with my new question.

I have a Thread 1 signal: SIGABRT error in App Delegate when I try to push the fire button in my game (The fire button is an SKSpriteNode.) Sometimes it will fire but only when I tap the button in very specific positions. Otherwise, it will give me the SIGABRT error. It is probably coming from code in my `touchesBegan` function,

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

for touch in touches {
    let location = (touch as UITouch).location(in: self)
    let nodes = self.nodes(at: location)
    for node in nodes {
        if node.name == "FireButton" {
            shoot()
        } else {
            let touchLocation = touch.location(in: self)
            spaceship.position.x = touchLocation.x
        }
     }
  }
}
```

the `fireLaser` function,

```
func fireLaser(laser: SKNode, toDestination destination: CGPoint, withDuration duration: CFTimeInterval, andSoundFileName soundName: String) {
  let laserAction = SKAction.sequence([
    SKAction.move(to: destination, duration: duration),
    SKAction.wait(forDuration: 3.0 / 60.0),
    SKAction.removeFromParent()
  ])

addChild(laser)
laser.run(SKAction.group([laserAction]))
}
```

or the `shoot` function.

```
func shoot() {
   self.laser.position = CGPoint(x: self.spaceship.position.x, y: 
   self.spaceship.position.y + self.spaceship.frame.height - 
   self.laser.frame.height/2)
   self.addChild(self.laser)
   let laserDestination = CGPoint(x: self.spaceship.position.x, y: 
      self.frame.height + self.laser.frame.height / 2)
      self.fireLaser(laser: self.laser, toDestination: laserDestination, withDuration: 1.0, andSoundFileName: "laser sound effect.mp3")
}
```

Here's a screenshot of the screen that I see when I get the error.
[Error Screenshot][1]

Also, here's the message that prints out in the console when I get the error,

```
2017-06-12 17:02:06.100 Galaga Copy[790:23281] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Attemped to add a SKNode which already has a parent: <SKSpriteNode> name:'(null)' texture:[<SKTexture> 'Laser' (27 x 150)] position:{-5.8244380950927734, -411.53384399414062} scale:{1.00, 1.00} size:{13.5, 75} anchor:{0.5, 0.5} rotation:0.00'
```

*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000105cfcb0b **exceptionPreprocess + 171
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010261f141 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000105d65625 +[NSException raise:format:] + 197
    3   SpriteKit                           0x0000000103218c95 -[SKNode insertChild:atIndex:] + 162
    4   SpriteKit                           0x0000000103218bd2 -[SKNode addChild:] + 68
    5   Galaga Copy                         0x0000000102036601 _TFC11Galaga_Copy9GameScene5shootfT_T_ + 1089
    6   Galaga Copy                         0x0000000102036f57 _TFC11Galaga_Copy9GameScene12touchesBeganfTGVs3SetCSo7UITouch_4withGSqCSo7UIEvent__T_ + 1431
    7   Galaga Copy                         0x0000000102037436 _TToFC11Galaga_Copy9GameScene12touchesBeganfTGVs3SetCSo7UITouch_4withGSqCSo7UIEvent__T_ + 102
    8   SpriteKit                           0x00000001032007c4 -[SKView touchesBegan:withEvent:] + 1130
    9   UIKit                               0x000000010347154b -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 2036
    10  UIKit                               0x0000000103472f00 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 4114
    11  UIKit                               0x000000010341fa84 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 352
    12  UIKit                               0x0000000103c035d4 __dispatchPreprocessedEventFromEventQueue + 2926
    13  UIKit                               0x0000000103bfb532 __handleEventQueue + 1122
    14  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000105ca2c01 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION** + 17
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000105c880cf __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 527
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000105c875ff __CFRunLoopRun + 911
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000105c87016 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 406
    18  GraphicsServices                    0x000000010a159a24 GSEventRunModal + 62
    19  UIKit                               0x0000000103402134 UIApplicationMain + 159
    20  Galaga Copy                         0x0000000102039b07 main + 55
    21  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000106c9c65d start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)

Sorry that It's all out of whack but I can't figure out how to make it show properly. Can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: Please could you also add the details of the what printed in the bottom right part of the screen.

Comment: You are adding the same node "laser" more than once. You must create a new instance of laser each time.

Comment: Another Idea that I had. Does anyone know how to make the ship just fire continuously without the user having to press the fire button? That would be easier to do as I wouldn't need to have the button which is complicating things a lot.

Answer (score 1):

`self.addChild(self.laser)`

may be your issue. Reassigning nodes without removing them from previous parents can cause this issue.

I suggest `.removeFromParent` first and see if that works. I noticed you put that in the `fire()` function, but it's possible that you are calling `shoot()` before that block gets run.

Comment: Yes, adding the laser again is the problem. The message when the app terminates is  'Attemped to add a SKNode which already has a parent: <SKSpriteNode> name:'(null)' texture:[<SKTexture> 'Laser' (27 x 150)], etc etc. The texture used there is Laser, which I guess you are using for your laser node.